# Kucoin Spot Trading Balance Retrieval Error: Invalid KC-API-SIGN (400005)

Tags: python, rest, authentication, hmac, kucoin

I'm trying to fetch my Kucoin spot trading balance using their REST API, but I'm encountering a 401 error with the message 'Invalid KC-API-SIGN'. Here's my Python code and the steps I've taken from [Kucoin Docs API](https://www.kucoin.com/docs/basic-info/connection-method/authentication/signing-a-message):

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
import requests

api_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
api_secret = 'YOUR_API_SECRET'
api_passphrase = 'YOUR_API_PASSPHRASE'

url = 'https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/accounts'
now = str(int(time.time() * 1000))
str_to_sign = now + 'GET' + '/api/v1/accounts'
signature = hmac.new(api_secret.encode('utf-8'), str_to_sign.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

passphrase = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(api_secret.encode('utf-8'), api_passphrase.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest())
headers = {
    "KC-API-SIGN": signature,
    "KC-API-TIMESTAMP": now,
    "KC-API-KEY": api_key,
    "KC-API-PASSPHRASE": passphrase,
    "KC-API-KEY-VERSION": "2"
}
response = requests.request('get', url, headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.json())
```

Double-checked API credentials:- I've meticulously verified my API key, secret, and passphrase.
Reviewed timestamp generation:-  I've ensured that the timestamp is in the correct format (milliseconds since Unix epoch).
Examined Kucoin documentation:-  I've carefully studied Kucoin's API docs for potential errors in my signature generation process.

Comment: Paste your auth details directly into the sample code they provide and see if that works. If it does, print the `headers` values from each to the screen from their code and yours and compare them. I noticed that you're using `hexdigest` rather than `digest` to create the signature - maybe that's causing problems?

Debug loads of stuff to screen and start from there

Comment: Yes now its working but now the data key has no any balance returned

{'code': '200000', 'data': []}

Comment: Now its fetching the balance after passing auth details as you said. intially one of my kucoin account had no balance that's why it was not giving me data. Thanks